# str2num and importing data for large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, import, xlsx

I have a large matrix in xlsx file which contains chars as following for example:

```
1,26:45:32.350,6,7,8,9,9,0,0,0

1,26:45:32.409,5,7,8,9,9,0,75,89
```

I want to make the 2nd column (the one which contains 26:45:32:350)
as a time vector and all the rest as a double matrix.

I tried the next code on like 50000 rows and it worked.

```
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.xlsx','XLSX Files');

fid = fopen(FileName);
T=char(importdata(FileName));

Time=T(:,5:16);

Data=str2double(T);
```

However, when I tested it on the whole matrix (about 500,000 roww), I recieved Data=[] instead of matrix.

Is there any other thing I can do so 'Data' will be double matrix even for large matrix?

- The excel file contains 1 column and around 500,000 rows, so the whole line `1,26:45:32:350,6,7,8,9,9,0,0,0` is inside 1 cell.

Also, I wrote another code,which works but take alot of time to run.

```
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.xlsx','XLSX Files');

fid = fopen(FileName);
T=importdata(FileName);
h = waitbar(0,'Converting Data to cell array, please wait...');
for i=1:length(T)
    delimiter_index=[0 find(T{i,1}(:)==char(44))'];
    for j=1:length(delimiter_index)-1
        Data{i,j}=T{i,1}(delimiter_index(j)+1:delimiter_index(j+1)-1);
    end
    waitbar(i/length(T));
end
close(h)
h = waitbar(0,'Seperating Data to time and data, please wait...');
for i=1:length(T)
    Full_Time(i,:)=Data{i,2};
    Data{i,2}=Data{i,1};
    Data{i,1}=Full_Time(i,:);
    waitbar(i/length(T));
end
close(h)
Data(:,1)=[];

h = waitbar(0,'Changing data cell to mat, please wait...');
for i=1:size(Data,1)
    for j=1:size(Data,2)
        Matrix(i,j)=str2num(Data{i,j});
    end
    waitbar(i/size(Data,1));
end
close(h)
```

Running this code for like 20000 rows shows that:(slowest to fastest)
waitbar
allchild
str2num
importdata

So basically I can remove this waitbar, but allchild (not sure what it is) and str2num take most of the time.

Is there anything I can do to make it run faster?

Comment: Did you receive any errors or warnings? It sounds like you might be exceeding the size of your containers.

Comment: No warnings, just Data=[]. what it mean exceeding the size of my containers?

Comment: Well, if you say that it worked for a subset of your matrix, then I can only imagine that your original file is too big to be processed just like that. But normally, MATLAB would notify you if that's the case, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: take a look at `xlsread`, it may be more suitable for what you'd want.

Comment: Tried xlsread(Filename) and it gave me now T=[];

Comment: How does the char T look like in your workspace? Is it neccessary to use the explicit `char(importdata(...))` instead of just `importdata(...)`? I guess there may be a problem with inconsistent string length in your "elements", i.e. `0` in one column and `75` in the other. Also, doesn't it have to be `32:409` instead of `32.409`? Maybe you can use `str2double(T(:,[1:4 17:nColumns]))`.

Comment: @ben Try this call `[num, txt, ~] = xlsread(FileName)`. Inspect the results in the global workspace and plan from there on., Namely, you'll get a matrix with second column set on `NaN`, and a cell array of strings in which you'll find the strings of you timestamps.

Comment: Hi' thanlk, i changed the time to 32.409 (should be like this instead of :).I also think that you are right about the 0 and 75 example but not sure how to solve it. when i run it without char, like this:'T=importdata(FileName);' i get like 500000x1 cell and in each cell there '1,26:45:32:350,6,7,8,9,9,0,0,0'. also, CST_Link, i tried your suggestion it gave me same result as just importdata(FileName)

Comment: What takes most of calculation time? Would be helpful if you could provide details from the Matlab profiler.